# If I have a sole proprietorship making under $30k, can I register an HST account but not charge HST?

Tags: canada, hst

Can I create an HST account for my sole proprietorship but not charge HST if I don't make more than $30k? Can my HST account just sit there?

Comment: Why do you want an account that would just sit there? If you had an account, you could be claiming input tax credits.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes, you could do that.

All that would be required by you is to file with the CRA at your elected intervals (e.g. quarterly or yearly). You must do this even if you have no sales or expenses for the given period.

That said, Chris W. Rea from above makes a good point. You'll generally want to claim ITCs if possible.